# PHP loop blocking the rest of the code to execute

Tags: php, logic

I have a scipt with a loop that looks a bit like this

```
[CODE]  [BIG LOOP] [SOME MORE CODE]
```

The problem I face is that as long as the loop is running, the php code don't go on and load the rest of the page ([SOME MORE CODE]). How could I work arround this issue ? Any pointers ?

The loop im executing is fetching data from a MYSQL database, downloading and saving images. After that it's deleting temporery MYSQL data.

But what the Loop is doing is not importent IMO every loop will block the ongoing code till the loop is done.

So my question is, is there any possility to execute the loop, but also go on in the code ? And if not (what I'm thinking) is there any logical solution how I could work arround this, as I want to load both "codeblocks" on this page. I think splitting the code in 2 .phps and inlcuding it seperated would face to same issue.

Comment: You need to optimize your loop.  You should provide information about what you are doing in that loop.

Comment: Obviously: don't execute such long-running code there. It's impossible to give any more constructive advice without knowing the details.

Comment: @AndreKR I think he ment to write it in pseudo code

Comment: @Hussam That's rather imaginary code.

Comment: one idea - run [BIG LOOP] in the background.

Comment: @Rubens pseudo code is more or less by definition imaginary, as long as it makes understanding code easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
[CODE]  [SOME MORE CODE]  [BIG LOOP]
```

But if "some more code" depends on "big loop", then you have a problem.  Here are a few ideas:

- Optimize your loop.  It is possible you have some kind of gross inefficiency in your loop.
- Do less work.  Maybe you don't need to process the entire big loop, and can do less processing.
- Cache your results.  If the same loop is being executed frequently and producing the same results, maybe you can save the results in a file/APC/memcached ?
- Use AJAX.  Load a page without the data from the big loop, and then have that page use AJAX to load the data you need.  You can present a page with a nice 'please wait while we get your data' message/icon/whatever.

Comment: It don't depends on the loop. It's just the footer of the site. But without it's looking ugly. So I'm searching a way to work arround. I will try some of your suggestions as I wanted to use AJAX anyway in this project.

Answer (score 0):

If `[BIG LOOP]` result needs to be calculated and also needs to appear in the HTML before `[SOME MORE CODE]` then : no workaround. I am saying this if `[CODE=HTML] [BIG LOOP=PHP] [SOME MORE CODE=HTML]`. Otherwise, be more precise (or give code). 
When you say "load the rest of the page" do you mean "load the HTML page"? In that case, all PHP code has to already have been executed.
Although you should probably proceed differently, here is a possible trick :

```
[CODE] [DIV FOR AJAX]  [SOME MORE CODE] [AJAX INSTRUCTION TO LOAD RESULT OF BIG LOOP IN DIV]
```

That, now, is a really smart way to probably be a bit brutal in terms of PHP programming!